# How can I wrap a group of elements with a simple line border?

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I'm making a form and I want to surround a group of inputs with a line as shown in the picture below:

[image: wrap div]

This is my code

```
<div class="selectMov" >
    <p>Tipo de Movimiento</p>
    <input type="radio" class="optTiMov" value=1> Entrada<br>
    <input type="radio" class="optTiMov" value=2> Salida<br>
</div>
```

I've seen this kind of element before, but I don't what it is called or how to make it

Comment: The element that does this is named `fieldset`

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm new with all of this and had no idea i couldn't do what I just did. I'll keep it in mind for the next occasion. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A simple way is to use [fieldset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp). Here is a similar example

```css
fieldset {
border 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text"><br>
  Email: <input type="text"><br>
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea it could be this simple hahah. Thank you so much.

Comment: @litaned Glad it helped.